# Reverse the order of rows at max-width 480px

Tags: html, css

I have a normal html/css layout as below. However, for max-width 480px, I want to reverse the order of section1 and section2. I use bootstrap.

I want section2 row to come before section1 row. How can I do that?

```
    <div class="container" id="content">
        <div class="row" id="section1">
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="section2">
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="section3">
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
```

Comment: I would suggest using flexbox.  I'll try to come up with an example to post.

Comment: Look into the pull and push classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox and alter the `order` property on the child you want to re-order.

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #section2 {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="content">
  <div class="row" id="section1">1
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="section2">2
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="section3">3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a flexbox option using order at a certain media query to only move the 2nd box before the first. The rest of the order would be the same:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  order: 2;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #section2 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```